# Resume or CV for Research Position?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, resume, research

I have recently started applying for research jobs. A lot of the applications for larger companies will start with attaching your resume. However, I am wondering if it may be better to attach my CV rather than resume for a research position. The CV may have more relevant information to the job, but I would not want to disqualify myself by attaching a CV when they ask specifically for a resume. I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or input on this for a young job seeker, thanks!

Comment: "Resume" and "CV" are just names (and have different connotations in different cultures). There isn't a hard and fast difference between them. In the document you send include whatever you need to convince them that you are the right person for the job - and don't include anything else.

Comment: Are these research jobs in academia or research jobs in industry?

Comment: Industry primarily.

Answer (score 2):

> I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or input on this for a young job seeker, thanks!

It's really difficult and "nerve-racking" submitting applications!

> I would not want to disqualify myself by attaching a CV when they ask specifically for a resume

The good news is **YOU WILL NOT DISQUALIFY YOURSELF**.

You're OK.

1. It is really hard to know whether to send a longer or shorter document, but,
2. You WILL NOT "disqualify" yourself - there is NO chance someone will look at it and say "Oh, this idiot sent an X when we asked for Y! My God! She's out!"  :-)

You have nothing to worry about specifically on that front. Choose what you feel is best based on the job ad.  Good luck!

I have to constantly submit proposals to prospects, and every single time I have more trepidation than you, and I'm probably older then your granddad!  Follow what you feel is best.